# Can jQuery acces js created by MVC Tag helpers

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, tag-helpers

I am building .NET Asp app using jqwidgets  MVC Tag Helpers.

In some scenarios I want extend or modfy JS created by tag helpers.

When I look at source page for my generated  view I get something like this

```
<jqx-grid>
    <div altrows="True" autorowheight="True" columnsresize="True" filterable="True" id="grid" pageable="True" serverProcessing="True" showfilterrow="True" sortable="True" sourceId="Id" sourceModel="core.Data.Mjenjacnica.MjeKlistDoc" sourceTotalRecords="TotalRecords" sourceUrl="./GetPageData">
</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function () 
        {var source = { 
            id: 'Id',
            dataFields: [ { name: 'BrojListe', type: 'string'}, { name: 'Datum', type: 'date'}, { name: 'Id', type: 'number'}],
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: './GetPageData',
            cache: false, 
            formatData: function(data){ return { 'jsonData': JSON.stringify(data)}; }, 
            beforeprocessing: function(data) { source.totalrecords = data.TotalRecords;}, 
            sort: function(data) { $('#grid').jqxGrid('updatebounddata', 'sort'); }, 
            filter: function(data) { $('#grid').jqxGrid('updatebounddata', 'filter'); }
            }; 
        var adapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);
        var grid= new jqxGrid($('#grid'),
            { altrows: true, 
            filterable: true, 
            showfilterrow: true, 
            pageable: true, 
            autorowheight: true, 
            sortable: true, 
            columnsresize: true,
            columns: [{ text: 'First Name', datafield: 'BrojListe', width: 150 }],
            virtualmode: true, 
            rendergridrows: function(obj) {return obj.data;},
            source: adapter });
            });
        </script>
</jqx-grid>
```

Is there any way I can on client using jQuery or something change this generated script.

I am trying to add extra param to url property of generated source inside this js.

Usually I can modify prams and methods of js inside

```
$(document).ready(function () {});
```

But can jQuery access JS created by taghelpers? And is it possible to rewrite some functions on client side?